# Вращаю дочерний объект меняется размер

Tags: unity3d

[image]И  так , здесь 4 цилиндра все одинакового размера , и все четыре цилиндра являются дочерними белого цилиндра , вопрос в том почему когда я вращаю дочерний цилиндр он меняет размер (как на картинке) убираю его с дочернего ,  цилиндр не имеет родителя тогда нет проблем вращаю и с размером все ок. Как исправить? Если возможно это.

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом, без него трудно понять, что вы делаете не так.

Comment: Если у всех ваших объектов разные, я бы даже сказал "пляшушие", значения Scale - то при локальном вращении дочернего объекта, если родительский объект так же со странными значениями Scale, - могут быть неожиданные визуальные эффекты.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, вращение относительно родителя не должно никак влиять на scale ребенка, на position влияет, да, но не на scale.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Scale остается неизменным, но внешний вид при вращении меняется (сужаясь, растягиваясь). Главное в таком эксперименте, что бы и дочерний, и родительский объекты были с разными значениями, отличными от 1 и отличными от других (н-р, как у автора вопроса 0,2/1,3/0,2)

Comment: @ХасанШаДиев, хотелось бы получить от Вас обратную связь. Решен ли вопрос? Если да, то необходимо его закрыть. Если нет - желательно отписаться по этому поводу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такой эффект деформации дочерних объектов при вращении связан с непропорциональным значением Scale 3D-объектов (и родителей, и дочерних).
В Вашем случае необходимо, как минимум, чтобы родитель (видимо, большой белый диск) имел Scale (1,1,1). А для этого нужно использовать другую, "правильную", 3D-модель. Это раз.

Два. Скорее всего текущие модели и их разный Scale возможно будет использовать, если все они будут дочерними пустому GameObject со сдандартным значением Scale - 1. Т.е. белый диск будет являться дочерним и не будет иметь вложенные красные точки, а сами эти точки будут вложены в этот же родительсий пустой объект.

Comment: Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, можете привести пример?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, накидал на скорую руку. Два цилиндра с нестандартными пропорциями. Пока не вращаем дочерний объект (X) - выглядит все как и задуманно. Вращаем - происходит визуальное искажение из-за Scale-родителя.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JtMeLk_MA5KTsVb_HOixxbdRSUP7p1k9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Забавно, не встречал такие вещи, благодарю за пример :)