# Unity3D Неправильно поворачивается объект

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Делаю небольшую игру на Unity и C#.
Проблема в том, что когда поворачивается объект, вместо поворота он растягивается (Коллайдер тоже). В чем может быть проблема?
[![Вот так все выглядит...][1]][1]

Я новичок, так что не очень знаю, что можно еще добавить

Ответ [Вращаю дочерний объект меняется размер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908291/)

Comment: Это из-за измененного масштаба объекта (0,05-1-0,0055). Сейчас найду ссылку на похожий вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908291/%d0%92%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80/908476#908476

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Все исправил, спасибо!

Comment: Поскольку, *на мой взгляд*, этот вопрос по своей сути дублирует тот, что я указал по ссылке, приводить **ответ** здесь считаю избыточным. Однако, если ответ в том вопросе решает Вашу проблему - проголосуйте за ответ там.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вращаю дочерний объект меняется размер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908291/%d0%92%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80)