# Модель "удлиняется" в вверх при наведении камеры вверх

Tags: c#, unity3d

Обьект(оружие) прикреплено к камере, если навести камеру вверх, то модель оружия начнёт удлинятся, при этом его размеры не увеличиваются, такая ошибка видна даже в сцене.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    float xRot, yRot;
    public GameObject view;
    float sensivity = 3f;

    void mouseMove(){
        xRot += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensivity;
        yRot -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensivity;

        view.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRot, xRot, 0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, xRot, 0f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        mouseMove();
    }
}
```

(за говнокод не бейте, если такой имеется)

[image: Поднял - удлинилось,]
[image: отпустил - уменшьлась]

Comment: думаю такое лучше показывать на видео. + показать с разной дистанции камеры - один раз с близи, один раз по-дальше разместить камеру от обьекта. Раз сам обьект не меняет размеров физически и не скелится - вероятнее всего это "проблема" настроек камеры каких-то - например эфект "рыбьего глаза" когда у камеры  растягиваются обьекты относительно центра изображения

Comment: Если автомат вложен в куб, то проблема в кубе - точнее в его скейле. См: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908291